# Power Supply Information

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, dell-poweredge, power-supply-unit

Is it possible to view power supply information of a remote Windows (2008) server? It's a Dell Poweredge R720

The physical server is in a remote location and I only have RDP access. I can't see anything looking at the system information.

Ideally I don't want to install any additional software.

Maybe this isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OSMA would be the most convenient option (if this is pre installed on the machine). Another option would be to request IPMI access to the server and from iDRAC, you can read all the information needed for the PSU.

Another work around could be to boot your server into Rescue mode (linux envoierment) and check it from there:

dmidecode --> https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode

https://www.unix.com/red-hat/244490-check-psu-status.html

Hope this helps you.

Best regards,

Adrian

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dell OpenManage (OMSA) to see this kind of information.

I hope it's already installed on the server since you don't want to install any additional software.